# unable to clear interval, React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a timer function it's working but when I click `clearInterval` it's not working, timer still going on.

Here is my function to start timer. Maximum limit for timer is 60sec

```
const StartRecord = ()=>{ 
const timeout = setInterval(() => {
        if (time != 60) {
          setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
        }
      }, 1000);
      console.log(timeout);

      if (time == 60) {
        clearInterval(timeout);
      }
}
```

here is my function to stop timer

```
  const onStopRecord = () => {
    clearInterval(time);
}
```

can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying clearInterval using time. It should be timeout

```
const onStopRecord = () => {
    clearInterval(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useEffect` to do this task

```
useEffect(() => {
 let interval
 if(time != 60){
    interval = setInterval(() => setTime((prev) => prev + 1), 1000);      
 }
 return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [time])
```